# PHP pagination, displaying only a few page links

Tags: php

I am at the tail end of the pagination portion and it was requested to only allow a few page number links at the bottom. Lets say two before and two after the current page if those pages exist.

```
if($pagination->total_pages() > 1) {
if($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
    echo "<a href=\"results.php?page=";
    echo $pagination->previous_page();
    echo "\">&laquo; Previous</a>";
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
    if($i == $page) {
        echo "<span class=\"current\">{$i}</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"doc_list.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a>";
    }
}

if($pagination->has_next_page()) {
    echo "<a href=\"results.php?page=";
    echo $pagination->next_page();
    echo "\">Next &raquo;</a>";
}
}
```

I will be very grateful for any guidance as I have no clue how to resolve this.

Comment: There are lots of pagination classes and examples, you just have take look at the source code really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show the current page plus/minus two, first calculate the minimum and maximum page numbers to show:

```
$min = max($page - 2, 1); // there are no pages < 1
$max = min($page + 2, $pagination->total_pages()); // and no pages > total_pages
```

and then display the links:

```
for($i = $min; $i <= $max; ++$i) {
    if($i == $page) {
        echo "<span class=\"current\">{$i}</span>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"doc_list.php?page={$i}\">{$i}</a>";
    }
}
```

You might also want to involve the display of first/previous/next/last page links with the above, but we 'll need to have a specification of what result we are going for before having a crack at it.

Comment: Had some computer issues, but up and running now. Works perfect, thank you so much. Still new to PHP so trying to rap my head around how this works, but I'll get it.